# Trying to install rpmfusion thru my OS X terminal- I figured out OS X terminal doesn't read Linux commands

Tags: boot, bash, root

I'm trying to install rpmfusion, but this is what the os x terminal replies. What am I doing wrong? I'm in as the root user. Just figured out that OS X terminal doesn't read Linux commands.

```
sh-3.2# yum install --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm

sh: rpm: command not found
sh: rpm: command not found
sh: yum: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The sh-3.2 sounds like you're in single user mode..

Either way, try it manually. (assuming you're using fc22)

```
wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-22.noarch.rpm
wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-22.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh rpmfusion-free-release-22.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh rpmfusion-nonfree-release-22.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...but it must be something in the setup of the root user ie single verses universal ...still having the same issues getting... command not found... I went to another computer and I'm having the exact same issues. Do you know how to go from a single root user to universal root?

Comment: I'm with @DragonLord, there is something amiss with the boot process.  If commands rpm and wget aren't found, you've got bigger problems on your hands :)

Comment: I'd agree but I tried on two different Mac computers and got the same error message from each computer. Both computers said command not found. I must be doing something wrong. Or is it possible both computers have something wrong with each of their boot processes? @DragonLord

Comment: @lth: We're working on the assumption that your system is running Fedora, as indicated by the tags that were originally on your question. However, you've edited the question to remove the [linux] and [fedora] tags. Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: Sorry I had originally added those tags because I am trying to install rpmfusion so I can then install the VirtualBox Fedora but I deleted those tags thinking it was misleading. I am just using my OS X terminal. Am I trying to do these installs all the wrong way? Again super sorry...I'm just trying to learn with videos and any feedback I can get.

Comment: Please edit this into your question—this fundamentally changes the nature of your question.

Comment: Ok just did. This is even my first time on Stack/Superuser, sorry if I have started off on the wrong foot.

Comment: Just want to say thank you to the people who took the time to try to help this beginner! I honestly appreciate it. I figured it out. OS X terminal doesn't understand Linux commands.

Comment: @lth, that is correct :)  This makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Yum and RPM are not normal commands of a basic OSX install. Even with the dev tools option, they are not normal commands. RPM is the Red hat Package Manager, and YUM is similar. You either need a special install for those, or use a similar package manager like Homebrew or Mac Ports. If those package managers have RPM Fusion available is another story.

Basically OSX is not Red Hat Linux.

If you want Virtual Box, with a Fedora virtualization, then you need to install Virtual Box, (or parallels) then install Fedora on that. You can then access regular fedora options through the virtualized Fedora.